# request a user to refresh a web page after time limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm curious if this concept is of any possibility, but can you request a user to refresh a web page after being idle on a web page for a certain time limit? Mainly for sites that have a shopping cart and the item may no longer be available.

Just a thought that may lead to some interesting ideas. Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Your idea is very good and I have implemented that using socket connection when anything changes regarding database i am emit the event and user get notification on browser for please refresh page. 
It is a very helpful to booking sites.+1

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [setTimeOut](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fire-event-when-user-is-idle/) to call a function in javascript, which will ask for a confirmation. This function can also show a div at the top which informs him of the session timeout, and press continue link there.
2. You can use [jquery inactivity](https://github.com/afklondon/jquery.inactivity) library like many other for idle timeout.
3. If you do not want to prompt user, [set Idle timeout in IIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx).
4. If you are working with classic ASP.net, you can [use AJAX Toolkit](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Session-Timeout-message-before-Session-expires-in-ASPNet.aspx).